# Twitter Bootstrap affix element width rolling out from parent element borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I create an panel element and inside his body put another panel element.
Than i put to this "inside-panel" an affix plugin and when i scroll down page
my "inside-panel" changing size and it not look nice. I wrote an example and put on bootply to show how it look like.
[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/dh0MDs4BxH)
I try to fix width with JS code:

```
    var sz = $('.affix').width();
    $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('.affix').width(sz);
    });
```

But no sense.
Please tell me how to fix "inside-panel" width and in perfect still stay an responsive.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stated in the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)..

> "you must provide CSS for the positioning and width of your affixed
>   content"

Of course, it all depends on what you think "look nice". [Here's an example](http://bootply.com/RUiDxG0OqI) forked from you Bootstrap. Notice the `#myAffix.affix` CSS used to control the position of your panel.

http://bootply.com/RUiDxG0OqI

Comment: @ Skelly Thx for reply, but i mean that affix panel after scroll still stay in border of parent panel. I wrote JS code exactly to set affix panel width (i don`t like css - joke). But in your example affix panel width will set in 100% of screen,  i want that affix panel stay in border of parent panel.

Answer (score 1):

Check the doc: http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.2.0/docs/javascript/#affix

You can listen for the `affixed.bs.affix` event and then detect the scrollspy parent's width and then set the scrollspy to match this width.

Here is my solution.

```
  $("#scroll-spy").on('affixed.bs.affix', function(e) {
    var wrapper = $("#scroll-spy-wrapper");
    var scrollSpy = $("#scroll-spy");

    scrollSpy.width(wrapper.width());
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Solve problem by calculating window\element sizes and set width in appropriate percent.